# How do I connect to MemSQL from Elixir

Tags: elixir, singlestore

[MemSQL](http://www.memsql.com) is binary compatible with Mysql and uses the same drivers. However this nice-in-theory does not seem to apply when you connect from Elixir with [mariaex](https://github.com/xerions/mariaex) or [mysqlex](https://github.com/tjheeta/mysqlex).

With mariaex, I can connect fine:
[image]

but I cannot query because of the enable_binary_protocol issue:

[image]

Enabling binary protocol in memsql.cnf for the aggregator kind of works for some short queries, but not for longer ones. First, after editing memsql.cnf to include the line "enable_binary_protocol=true" and restarting the cluster using "memsql-ops memsql-restart" I checked that the parameter was indeed set:

[image]

And now some stuff works, but not others:

[image]

BTW that query works fine in the memSQL command line interface:

[image]

The mysqlex driver, meantime, does not even connect:

[image]

So I'm basically stumped. Is anybody successfully using Elixir with memSQL? If so, what's the secret ingredient?

One option might be to use an Erlang library. [This one](https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp) ([also available on Hex](https://hex.pm/packages/mysql)) might be good but I have no idea how to call the Erlang functions from Elixir. The closest I got was successfully compiling it in iex after adding the dependency {:mysql, "~> 1.0"} to my mix.exs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with `MemSQL` but it [*does look*](https://mysql-otp.github.io/mysql-otp/index.html) like [`mysql-otp`](https://github.com/mysql-otp/mysql-otp) prepares query statements on the client side. You can try using it like this:

```
# Connect
{:ok, pid} = :mysql.start_link(host: 'localhost', user: 'foo', password: 'hello', database: 'test')

# Select
{:ok, columns, rows} = :mysql.query(pid, "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = ?", [1])

# Transactions
result = :mysql.transaction(pid, fn ->
  :ok = :mysql.query("INSERT INTO mytable (foo) VALUES (1)")
  raise "foo"
  :ok = :mysql.query("INSERT INTO mytable (foo) VALUES (1)")
end)
```

See the [official Erlang/Elixir crash course](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#erlang) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.memsql.com/docs/prepared-statements. There should be a client setting to use client-side prepared statements only - many examples are listed on that page. That is the recommended way to get such clients to connect.

Comment: I have seen this list of docs, but I have no way of knowing which one of these mariex and or mysqlex use. Indeed I am not convinced that they use any of them because both are pure elixir libraries.